# Jersey 2.8, grizzly, SSE: what jar files do i have to download

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0, grizzly

aI am trying to upgrade my jersey-jar files from 1x to 2.8 version. To download them, everyone is pointing [here](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/jersey/). Obviously, i can download and import all of them but i believe that 5-6 should be sufficient for me. I have searched but i did not find something that says which of them to download.

My app is implementing just a simple Rest API, hosted by a grizzly server and need to have Server Sent Events (SSE).

Can anyone tell me what jars do i have to download?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to use Maven?

Comment: unfortunately, it is not my decision on how to include the required libraries, so i have to stay with jars..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If hate having to find what dependencies I need, as jars depend on other jars that depend on other jars. Even if I have to work on a project that doesn't use Maven, I will still create a new project, adding core dependencies, and see what they pull in. From there I can just grab em from the repo. For example a project with Grizzly-Jersey-JerseySSE

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Pulls in all this

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what i need. Generally, the approach "create a new project, add core dependencies, and see what they pull in" that you proposed is a good generic solution for every similar problem. Thanks again.